# How to calculate distance between two coordinates in google map?

Tags: android

I had plotted two points in Google Map. I want to compute the distance between the two points in terms of road way. Any solution or working code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use following method for calculating distance between two lat-long points.

```
public static float distFrom (float lat1, float lng1, float lat2, float lng2 ) 
{
    double earthRadius = 3958.75;
    double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
    double dLng = Math.toRadians(lng2-lng1);
    double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *
    Math.sin(dLng/2) * Math.sin(dLng/2);
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
    double dist = earthRadius * c;

    int meterConversion = 1609;

    return new Float(dist * meterConversion).floatValue();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through the APIs: there is a ComputeDistanceBetween function in the "geometry" library, "spherical" namespace. Reference: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry

It is used this way:

```
var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(latLong, latLong);
```